# rowspan table td containing textareas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So far so good i have been able to merge table rows with the text in the td, but text in the textarea has not gone through. My table

```
Column1 | column2 | column3 | Column4
--------------------------------------
 Assay  |  Source | label  |   3%
-------------------------------------
 Assay  |  Source | label  |   10%
-------------------------------------
```

What I would like to accomplish

```
Column1 | column2 | column3 | Column4
--------------------------------------  //Note that Column1 has
        |        |         |   3%       //no textarea, just td text
 Assay  - Source -   label -----------  //While all the rest have
        |        |         |   10%      //textareas in the tds
-------------------------------------   // from column 2 - 4
```

I have this code that works only for tds without textareas. How do I merge also rows that have textareas having same data?

```
function merge() {
  $('.result_table').each(function() {
    var Column_number_to_Merge = 1;

    // Previous_TD holds the first instance of same td. Initially first TD=null.
    var Previous_TD = null;
    var i = 1;
    $("tbody", this).find('tr').each(function() {
      // find the correct td of the correct column
      // we are considering the table column 1, You can apply on any table column
      var Current_td = $(this).find('td:nth-child(' + Column_number_to_Merge + ')');

      if (Previous_TD == null) {
        // for first row
        Previous_TD = Current_td;
        i = 1;
      } else if (Current_td.text() == Previous_TD.text()) {
        // the current td is identical to the previous row td
        // remove the current td
        Current_td.remove();
        // increment the rowspan attribute of the first row td instance
        Previous_TD.attr('rowspan', i + 1);
        i = i + 1;
      } else {
        // means new value found in current td. So initialize counter variable i
        Previous_TD = Current_td;
        i = 1;
      }
    });
  });
}
```

HTML

```
<table class="table table-condensed col-md-12 result_table">
  <thead style="border:solid black 1px;">
    <td class="side">TEST</td>
    <td class="tdbold">METHOD</td>
    <td class="tdbold">COMPENDIA</td>
    <td class="tdbold">SPECIFICATION</td>
    <td class="tdbold">DETERMINED</td>
    <td class="side">REMARKS</td>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr valign="middle" align="center">
      <td style="font-size:13px; " class="tbody_data side" rowspan="2">Assay</td>
      <td valign="middle" align="center" style="padding: 0px;" class="tbody_data">
        <input type="hidden" value="6" name="tests[]">
        <textarea style="border: medium none; vertical-align: middle; height: 79px;" class="det_st form-control">HPLC</textarea>
      </td>
      <td style="padding: 0px;" class="tbody_data">
        <textarea style="border: medium none; height: 79px;" class="det_st form-control">Adopted In-House Method</textarea>
      </td>
      <td style="padding: 0px;" class="tbody_data">
        <textarea style="border: medium none; height: 79px;" class="det_st form-control">92.5 - 107.5%</textarea>
      </td>
      <td style="padding: 0px;" class="tbody_data">
        <textarea style="border: medium none; height: 82px;" class="det_st form-control">Day 1 105.3% (RSD=1.5%; n=6)</textarea>
      </td>
      <td class="tbody_data side">
        <select style="border:none; margin:15px; width:145px;" class="select" selected="selected">
          <option value="COMPLIES">COMPLIES</option>
          <option value="COMPLIES">COMPLIES</option>
          <option value="DOES NOT COMPLY">DOES NOT COMPLY</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr valign="middle" align="center">

      <td valign="middle" align="center" style="padding: 0px;" class="tbody_data">
        <input type="hidden" value="6" name="tests[]">
        <textarea style="border: medium none; vertical-align: middle; height: 79px;" class="det_st form-control">HPLC</textarea>
      </td>
      <td style="padding: 0px;" class="tbody_data">
        <textarea style="border: medium none; height: 79px;" class="det_st form-control">Adopted In-House Method</textarea>
      </td>
      <td style="padding: 0px;" class="tbody_data">
        <textarea style="border: medium none; height: 79px;" class="det_st form-control">92.5 - 107.5%</textarea>
      </td>
      <td style="padding: 0px;" class="tbody_data">
        <textarea style="border: medium none; height: 102px;" class="det_st form-control">Day 7 102.9% (RSD=0.27%; n=6)</textarea>
      </td>
      <td class="tbody_data side">
        <select style="border:none; margin:15px; width:145px;" class="select" selected="selected">
          <option value="COMPLIES">COMPLIES</option>
          <option value="COMPLIES">COMPLIES</option>
          <option value="DOES NOT COMPLY">DOES NOT COMPLY</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: *"I have this code"* isn't a question. What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do, but it looks like this line:

```
if (Current_td.text() == Previous_TD.text())
```

could be changed to:

```
 if (Current_td.text() == Previous_TD.text()
      || Current_td.find("textarea").val() == Previous_TD.find("textarea").val())
```

Comment: I am trying to merge rows that have textareas too, so instead of each row having a textarea with same data, i want to do away with the rest and remain with one textarea on that particular row span

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be on this line

```
  var Current_td = $(this).find('td:nth-child(' + Column_number_to_Merge + ')');
```

On your First row, The `var Column_number_to_Merge = 1;` will result in the column containing `Assay` to be set to `Previous_TD`.

On your second row, `Current_td` is pointing to the textarea. so the contents never match.

I'd recommend setting a `data` attribute on the columns and comparing the values using them. or group your data on the server and write it on the dom in the way you need it to be displayed.

Comment: `data-` attribute is ideal if the data is short (eg one or two words).  If it's in the range of paragraphs, then this is not such a good idea.

Comment: At which point does `Current_td` get set to point to a textarea?

Comment: I meant `Current_td` would be pointing to the `td` which has the textarea. Not the actual textarea by itself.

Comment: By `data` attribute, I meant something like this `data-method`, `data-compendia`, ... so that it is possible to do a column selection using something like `[data-method]`